# What is the best to find a developer to create a Craft plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I have the Craft Commerce based webshop and need a developer to create plugin for Klarna Checkout (https://knowledge.klarna.com).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options, as far as I know:

- [Straight Up Craft](https://straightupcraft.com/professionals) community site
- [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/community) has a jobs channel
- [Work With Craft](https://www.workwithcraft.com/)